# Issue with a UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, subclass, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a main viewController, it is called `WelcomeViewController`.  I have a UIView subclass and that has some view related stuff in it.  I want to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to that subclass.  I only want the gesture recognizer to acknowledge taps inside that subview.  How do I do that.  Should I put the `UITapGestureRecognizer` in the subclass or should I put it in the Welcome vc.  Thanks in advance.

Also, I have played around with it a bunch and can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 18):

It depends on whether you want to handle the tap in your custom view object or in the view controller.

If in the view, add this to it's `init` or other proper place:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[self addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
[tapRecognizer release];
```

If in the view controller, add this in the `viewDidLoad` (or other proper place):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[yourCustomView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
[tapRecognizer release];
```

handler is the same:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    // Do Your thing. 
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
    }
}
```

Take a look at the [SimpleGestureRecognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleGestureRecognizers/Introduction/Intro.html) example and you should get a pretty good idea.

**---- Updated 10/1/2012----**

For those of you who like to use storyboard/nib, this is super simple!

1. Open your storyboard/nib.
2. Drag-b-drop the kind of recognizer you want from the Object Library onto the UI element you want.
3. Right-click on the recognizer object, then connect its `selector` to an IBAction in the File's Owner (usually an UIViewController.) If you need to, connect the delegate as well.
4. You're done![image]

Comment: I'm good with all that.  The problem is I subclassed a UIView into my main view.  Now, which view do I add the UITapGestureRecognizer to.  The subview (which isn't working) or the main view (which makes it work when I tap anywhere, including outside the subview)

Comment: I've refined my answer. Does that make more sense to your situation?

Comment: Your main view might not pass events to subview. Also, you can check if touch point is in subview frame.

Comment: How can I check if the touch point is in the subview.  I think I will just do that and then call the method in the other class from that.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That helps, but I would prefer to handle the gesture from the custom view.  If that is not possible I can just call the method in the custom view from the viwController

Comment: That's the first part of my answer. Just add that to your custom view's init method.

Comment: If you decide to put the code into the `init` method of your subclass of `UIView` be sure to override the correct init method. If your View is instantiated inside of IB you need to override `initWithCoder:`, if you instantiate it programmatically you need to override `initWithFrame`. See this [SO-Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12202213/641514).

Comment: thanks @JosephLin  with a very small amount of tweaking your solution worked for me with a text view in the viewDidLoad.  I was trying to figure out how do that via the storyboard in iOS 6  but it was not obvious. Your simple solution just works. :D

Comment: @sdjuan, adding a gesture recognizer in the storyboard is even simpler! I've updated my post a bit to include that. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to set the delegate of the gesture recognizer to be whatever view controller you want to handle the taps.

```
gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

for example. Then adopt the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol in your header.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the receiver of the `UITapGestureRecognizer`, it doesn't have to be the same class that instantiated the recognizer (i.e. `self`). If you create it in your `WelcomeViewConroller`, you can select any subview to receive the events:

```
[tapRecognizer addTarget:aSubview action:@selector(myMethod:)];
```

Comment: No, that part I'm fine with.  Which subview do I add the gesture Recognizer to.

Comment: The subview that will respond to the tap(s).

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have the same problem I experienced. When you call [yourCustomView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer]; you need to reference via a UIView * so in your example
try:

```
UIView *mySubView = yourCustomView; 
[mySubView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please check `view.userInteractionEnabled=true;`