# TapGestureRecognizer does not get called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Hi in the main WiewController in the viewDidLoad i set up a

```
UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(processTap)];
```

and then i a for loop i create UIViews and add them to a scroll view, that is then added to the main view.

```
       UIView *newsContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160 * countnews, 30, 156, 126)];
       newsContainer.tag = countnews;
       newsContainer.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
       [newsContainer addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];            
       [tempScroll addSubview:newsContainer];
```

then i have a function

```
- (void)processTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    UIView *view = recognizer.view;
    NSLog(@"HELLO, %d", view.tag);
}
```

Which never gets called, any suggestions? your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

here is the entire .m

```
#import "iPadMainViewController.h"
#import "GradeintView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>
#import "Category.h"
#import "News.h"
#import "LazyImageView.h"
#import "TouchView.h"

@interface iPadMainViewController ()

@end

@implementation iPadMainViewController

@synthesize detailsView = _detailsView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(processTap:)];
    [recognizer setDelegate:self];

    GradeintView *MainTitle = [[GradeintView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 50)];
    GradeintView *MainSubTitle = [[GradeintView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 1024, 30)];

    NSMutableArray *categoriesCollection = [[Category alloc] allCategoriesFromFeedAtUrl:@"http://geonews.ge/xml/category.php"];

    UIScrollView *categories = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 512, 768)];
    _detailsView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(500, 0, 512, 768)];
    [_detailsView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [categories setScrollEnabled:TRUE];
    [categories setContentSize:CGSizeMake(500, categoriesCollection.count * 156)];

    MainTitle.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    MainTitle.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3, 3);
    MainTitle.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
    MainTitle.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;

    [categories setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    int counter = 0;

    for (Category *cat in categoriesCollection)
    {
        UIView *categoryTitle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 166 * counter
                                                                         , 500, 20)];

        UILabel *categoryLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, 200, 20)];

        [categoryLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        NSMutableArray *allCurrentNews = [[News alloc] allNewsFromCategory:cat.CategoryId];

        categoryLabel.text = cat.Name;
        categoryLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [categoryTitle addSubview:categoryLabel];

        UIColor *myblack = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.14 green:0.14 blue:0.14 alpha:1];
        UIColor *ligheterBlac = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.227 green:0.22 blue:0.22 alpha:1];
        [categoryTitle setBackgroundColor:myblack];

        UIScrollView *tempScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 166 * counter, 500, 166)];

        UIColor *tempcolor = ligheterBlac; 
        tempScroll.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.34 green:0.34 blue:0.34 alpha:1].CGColor;
        tempScroll.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
        int countnews = 0;

        for (News *news in allCurrentNews)
        {
            UIView *newsContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160 * countnews, 30, 156, 126)];
            newsContainer.tag = countnews;
            [newsContainer addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

            //newsContainer.NewsId = news.NewsId;
            LazyImageView *image = [[LazyImageView alloc] initWithURl:[NSURL URLWithString:news.Thumbnail]];
            image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0 , 156, 96);
            UILabel *newsTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 96, 156, 30)];
            newsTitle.backgroundColor = myblack;
            newsTitle.numberOfLines = 2;
            newsTitle.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
            newsTitle.text = news.Title;
            newsTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            newsTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

            newsContainer.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.34 green:0.34 blue:0.34 alpha:1].CGColor;
            newsContainer.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;

            [newsContainer addSubview:image];
            [newsContainer addSubview:newsTitle];

            countnews ++;
            [tempScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(allCurrentNews.count * 156, 96)];
            [tempScroll addSubview:newsContainer];
           //[image release];
        }

        [tempScroll setBackgroundColor: tempcolor];

        [categories addSubview:tempScroll];
        [categories addSubview:categoryTitle];
        [tempcolor release];
        [tempScroll release];
        counter ++;
    }

    self.detailsView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    self.detailsView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-10, 5);
    self.detailsView.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
    self.detailsView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;


    [self.detailsView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.amazon.com"]]];
    [self.view addSubview:categories];
    [self.view addSubview:self.detailsView];
    [self.view addSubview:MainSubTitle];
    [self.view addSubview:MainTitle];

}

- (void)processTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    UIView *view = recognizer.view;
    NSLog(@"HELLO, %d", view.tag);
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)loadDetailedContent:(NSString *)s
{
}

@end
```

Comment: Refer to this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more)

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
initWithTarget:self.view
```

to

```
initWithTarget:self
```

**EDIT:**
You also have forgotten colon:

```
initWithTarget:self action:@selector(processTap:)
```

**EDIT2:**
You have created `_detailsView` (with assigned UITapGestureRecognizer) but have not added it to any subview. How it will work?

Comment: assumes that all the code is called in the 'main WiewController'

Comment: i feel desperate :( adding a colon did not help as well

Comment: _detailsView does't matter for now, I'm working on newsContainer

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is that the scrollView, which contains your views, has its own internal gesture recognizer that is "taking away" touch events from your tap gesture recognizer. Try implementing the following gesture recognizer delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: As I'm quite unfamilliar with this, can you please explain exactly where and how to add this, i think this is the solution

Comment: Well, your `iPadMainViewController` is your TapGestureRecognizer's delegate. So if you copy the above method into iPadMainViewController's implementation, it should work.

Comment: Oh, and in your `viewDidLoad`, don't forget to call `[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer]` - I think you're still missing that.

Comment: I di all of those, but still no result, I must be doing something terribly wrong

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked the Interaction setting?
Interaction shall be set to "User Interaction Enabled" in the Attributes inspector for the image.

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(processTap)];
[newsContainer addGestureRecognizer::gestureRecognizer];
 gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

Comment: change [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];  to [newsContainer addGestureRecognizer::gestureRecognizer];

Answer (score 2):

Change @selector(processTap) to @selector(processTap:)

Because now you calling method that doesn't exist.

Comment: +1, This should do it. Also, while you're at it, do ensure that `- (void)processTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;` method is declared in your `.h` file as well

Comment: I did it but still nothing, anyway ho is the tap gesture simulated in the simulator, is it a click or should i be doing something else?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is, you might have missed to add `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` in the header file.

Comment: Yes i did, unfortunately it did not help

Comment: did you set [recognizer setDelegate:self]; as well

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more try this tut. this may be useful

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a `UIGestureRecognizer` to a `UIWebview`, which is not recommended. `UIWebview has its own`UIGestureRecognizer`s which are tricky to over-ride. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909807/does-uigesturerecognizer-work-on-a-uiwebview) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

you can first add your gestureRecognizer to self.view and check your method called or not...   as well check this thread
                                                                              [Issue with a UITapGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954934/issue-with-a-uitapgesturerecognizer)