# Implementing UITapGestureRecognizer directly into UIView instead of ViewController does not work

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

As explained in [this SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954934/issue-with-a-uitapgesturerecognizer) I am trying to implement `UITapGestureRecognizer` in a subclass of `UIIMageView`. My approach can be found below.

An instance of `MenuButtonImageView` is a subview of `homeScreenViewController.view`.

I implemented `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `touchesMoved:withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent:` too and do work fine.

**Problem**: Somehow `handleSingleFingeredTap:` is never called. What could be the problem with this?

```
@interface MenuButtonImageView : UIImageView

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet HomescreenViewController *homeScreenViewController;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) Visibility visibility;

- (void)handleSingleFingeredTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;

@end

@implementation MenuButtonImageView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.visibility = HIDDEN;
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        UITapGestureRecognizer * singleFingeredTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleFingeredTap:)];
        singleFingeredTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:singleFingeredTap];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)handleSingleFingeredTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"handleTap was called"); // This method is not called!
    [self toggleMainMenu];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { ... }
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { ... }
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { ... }

@end
```

Comment: maybe it's not working because you set visibility to hidden? set `numberOfTouchesRequired = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the recognizer in `initWithFrame` method. Check if your view is initialized this way. It may be created with another constructor like `initWithCoder`, and then your code is not executed. Put a breakpoint inside `initWithFrame` method to find out.

You can put the code in a separate method and call it from both constructors. It depends on how you use it. The `initWithFrame` is used quite common when you create a view from code.